# So I was trying to make an Photon Network connection where the players are spawned randomly but came across this error. No overload on 'Instantiate''

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

it is showing this error

> No overload for method 'Instantiate' Takes three arguments

For this line

```
PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(PlayerPrefabs.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn_Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayerPrefabs;
    public float minx;
    public float maxx;
    public float miny;
    public float maxy;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(minx, maxx),1, Random.Range(miny,maxy));
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(PlayerPrefabs.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: See [`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate`](https://documentation.help/Photon/class_photon_network.html#a32439a6fb4074a187d1458dcad022fcf) it has at least 4 parameters

Answer (score 1):

`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` takes at least 4 arguments if I'm not wrong.

1.Prefab

2.Position

3.Rotation

4.And [the interest group](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/interestgroups#instantiate)

Additionally you can add a 5th parameter used for [custom instantiation data.](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation#custom_instantiation_data)

Comment: I tried what u had said `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(PlayerPrefabs.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity,0);` . The player is not moving using this script

Comment: That should be a different question @hammish , probably you had to read more about how PhotonNetwork works and how "interest groups" affects your instantiated elements